# Angular function binding in custom directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, window

**Custom directive function binding with isolated scope is not working, and I have no idea why?**

I have `dropdown` directive which works as expected and when a value gets changed `dropValueChanged` function gets called.

In my directive, I am using that like following:

```
angular.module('app.directive').directive('myExtraDropdown',myExtraDropdown);

myExtraDropdown.$inject =  ['$compile'];
 function myExtraDropdown() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: 'true',
        scope: {
          ctrlFn:"&"
        },
        templateUrl: "src/templates/my-extra-dropdown.html",

        link: function(scope) {

        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'UtilService', function($scope,UtilService) {
            var self = this;

            self.dropValueChanged = function(item) {
                self.ctrlFn({id:item.value});
            };


        }],
       controllerAs: 'myExtraDrpdwnCtrl'
  }
}
```

I am using the directive like:

```
<div class="left-menu pull-left">
  <my-extra-dropdown ctrl-fn="myCtrl.ctrlFn(id)">
  </my-extra-dropdown>
</div>
```

And, in my `ctrl` , **I have function defined but it does not get called.**

```
angular.module('my.workspaces').controller('myController',myController);
myController.$inject =  ['$scope', '$rootScope','$location'];
    function myController($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
        var self = this;

        self.ctrlFn = function(id) {
           let oldUrl = $location.href;
        }
```

My the function does not get called.

**DETAILS**

But if we change in my `directive` to call like

```
$scope.ctrlFn({id:item.value});
```

and in my controller instead of `self` if I do

`$scope.ctrlFn`

**then it gets called**. **But $location is not accessible inside it.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When an isolate scope is used for a directive, `bindToController: true` will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope. See [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - bindToController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-bindtocontroller-)

Comment: Where is _myCtrl_ defined?